# Unable to save binary images data from a numpy array to a video file using openCV Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, dataset

I'm reading a binary video file that has 54 frames of depth image data that was taken by the Kinect sensor.

I'm able to read the data frame by frame and show it by following the code below:

```
# Load the depth map data from the binary file
with open(dataset_path + filename, "rb") as f:
    i,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # frame count
    w,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # width
    h,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # height

    for _ in range(i):
        bytesread = f.read(320*240*4)

        depth_data = np.frombuffer(bytesread, dtype=np.uint32)

        depth_map = depth_data.reshape((240, 320))

        plt.imshow(depth_map, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

However, when I try to save frames together to construct a video, it does not work. The code below generates the video file without errors, but I can't open it.

```
with open(dataset_path + filename, "rb") as f:
    i,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4)) # frame count
    w,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4)) # width
    h,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4)) # height

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("vid.mov", fourcc, 15, (w, h))

    for _ in range(i):
        bytesread = f.read(w*h*4)

        depth_data = np.frombuffer(bytesread, dtype=np.uint32)
        depth_map = depth_data.reshape((240, 320))

        out.write(depth_map.astype(np.uint8))
    out.release()
```

I've also tried different codecs without luck!

Comment: you told the VideoWriter to expect color data. you did not give it color data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @christoph's comment I looked it up and after some tweaks I was able to get it working using the below code:

```
# Load the depth map data from the binary file
with open(dataset_path + filename, "rb") as f:
    i,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # frame count
    w,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # width
    h,  = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))  # height

    depth_data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint32)
    depth_map = depth_data.reshape((i, h, w))

    # plt.imshow(depth_map[32], cmap='gray')
    # plt.show()

    output_video_path = "video.avi"

    # specify the frame rate of the output video
    fps = 30

    # create a VideoWriter object to write the output video
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
        output_video_path, fourcc, fps, (w, h), isColor=False)

    # iterate over each depth frame and write it to the output video
    for i in range(i):
        # normalize the depth map to 8-bit grayscale values for visualization
        depth_frame = (
            depth_map[i]/np.max(depth_map[i])*255).astype(np.uint8)
        # write the current depth frame to the output video
        video_writer.write(depth_frame)

    # release the VideoWriter object and close the output video file
    video_writer.release()
```